Why does my Spring GET Controller not redirecting to my Thymeleaf template when using Spring Reactive Rendering?
I am using Spring Reactive Rendering in my GET controller to return a Thymeleaf template.  I have my template file in the `resources/templates/yoman.html'.
When I attempt to access my endpoint at http://localhost:9093/admin/clients/hello the controller executes but it does not go to my yoman.html but just stays on the http://localhost:9093/admin/clients/hello after going thru the controller.
The following is my controller returning a Mono<Rendering>:
   @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<Rendering> hello() {
        final String PATH = "yoman";
        LOG.info("returning yo man");
        return Mono.just(Rendering.view(PATH).modelAttribute("client", "I am a client").build());
    }


